# flexanimate only working once

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flexslider

I am trying to control the flex slider movement using keyboard via jquery and angularjs but it only works once(FlexAnimate) and not again. Can anybody tell me why it is not working again

```
angular.element("#g-m").keyup(function(e){
      var p = angular.element("#slider").data('flexslider');
      var target = null;
      if(e.keyCode == 39){
       target  = p.getTarget('next');
      }
      if(e.keyCode !=37 && e.keyCode !=39){
        target = false;
      }
      p.flexAnimate(target , p.vars.pauseOnAction);
    });
```

**UPDATE**

If I don't touch the keyboard left and right arrow button and use the mouse only then slides keeps on moving but once I press the right and left button it moves one slide next or previous and then flexAnimate doesn’t do anything (It does not moves the slides)

P.S:I have used the flexslider keyboard option but that also doesn’t works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of figured out the problem the target was not being updated. What I did is after flexAnimate I had a if else in which I check if the keyCode was 39 then I incremented target and if 37 then I am decrmenting it